# Change Data Capture: suddenly stopped working

Tags: apex, trigger, change-data-capture

This is really bizare but is happening in production and not in the sandbox. I have 2 triggers for two objects, that I have enable in the Change data capture panel. This triggers were already in production and they were working unitl last week, no new deplyments have been made.

I have turn on the debug logs for Process, Automated, and this was login before and in sandbox but in production no logs have been recorded

When this start failing I run the test classes and this triggers have 0% coverage, that is pretty bizare as I wouldnt be able to deploy them. Regardless of this, I created a new test class that have the code coverage in the sandbox (Yes, the test class includes):

```
Test.enableChangeDataCapture();
```

and

```
Test.getEventBus().deliver();
```

But when I try to deploy this class in production I get the error of:

The following triggers have 0% code coverage. Each trigger must have at least 1% code coverage.

- OpportunityChangeTrigger
- FacebookEventChangeEvent

I am not really sure what could be my next move, but it feels that I might be missing something to actually trigger the change data capture

---

I just refreshed the sandbox and rerun the test class that doesnt want to be deploy in production, the test class in the refreshed sandbox runs and the 2 triggers have test coverage

Comment: any update on this please

Comment: no, it was really bizard i have to stop relaying on it